# SFTP doesn't work with Foriegn Characters?

Tags: sftp

Is that possible to transfer the files(which are in foreign characters) like Korean/Chinese/Japanese character encodings through SFTP?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Basically it is problematic, because of `libedit` support for such characters. But as an alternative, I would recommend you to try to use `scp` which deals quite well with unicode.

Comment: why -1? What you don't like on this answer?